# What is the probability that a ball lands in a bin?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Consider the classic problem of throwing *balls to bins*.
As usual, balls are thrown uniformly at random, and independently from one another, to the bins.

Let $N,B$ denote the number of balls and bins respectively.

Contrarily to the classic problem, however, balls can be discarded.
Each ball is discarded with probability $\alpha$.
Alike for the throws, balls are discarded independently from each other.

For each bin $b_{i}$, let $S_{i}$ denote a random variable corresponding to the number of balls landing in $b_{i}$.

What is the value of $P\left\{S_{i} = 0\right\}$?

(Note: if all balls were tossed, $P\left\{S_{i} = 0\right\} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{B}\right)^{N}$)

Comment: Hint:  the probability that a ball misses a fixed bin is $a+(1-a)(1- \frac {1}B)$

Comment: @lulu, would it be $\left( a + (1-a).(1-\frac{1}{B}) \right)^{N}$?

Comment: Yes, though I would simply and write $a+(1-a)(1- \frac {1}B)=1-\frac {1-a}B$

Comment: @lulu, thank you so much. I do not have enough points to upvote you, so all I can do is to thank you within a comment :)

Comment: and, what should I do with this question now?

Comment: You can post your own solution and accept it.  Good exercise to write out the argument fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simpler problem where N = 1 (*i.e.* there is only a single ball), and a fixed bin $b_{i}$.

The probability that the ball is discarded is $\alpha$.

If the ball is not discarded, the probability that it lands in $b_{i}$ is $\frac{1}{B}$. On the other hand, if the ball is tossed, the probability that it does not land in $b_{i}$ is $1 - \frac{1}{B}$.

Now, we can compute the probability that the ball does not land in $b_{i}$:

- The ball can either be discarded (with probability $\alpha$).
- Or it was tossed but simply did not hit the bin (with probability $\left(1 - \alpha\right) . \left(1 - \frac{1}{B}\right)$).

Summing up, the probability that the ball does not target $b_{i}$ is $\alpha + \left(1 - \alpha \right) . \left(1 - \frac{1}{B}\right) =  \left(1 - \frac{1 - \alpha}{B}\right)$.

Now, we only have to generalize this result to an arbitrary number of balls, denoted by $N$.
Since throws are independent from each other, the probability that none (out of $N$) hits $b_{i}$ is: $$P\left\{S_{i} = 0\right\} = \left( 1 - \frac{1 - \alpha}{B}\right)^{N}$$

Comment: A correction:  The second way for the ball to miss the given bin requires two things to happen.  First, it must not be discarded (probability $1-a$).  Second, it must then miss the bin (conditioned on not being discarded, the probability is $1-\frac 1B$.  Thus the probability the second path is the product $(1-a)\times(1-\frac 1B)$.  To see that what you wrote is wrong, let $a=1$.  Then the probability that the ball misses the given bin is certainly $1$, but according to your formula it should be $2-\frac 1B$, which is generally $>1$.

Comment: @lulu, I am sorry to have answered incorrectly. I have to thank you again for noting my mistake and saying how it could be corrected.

Comment: No problem at all.